# MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the “Koopa Troopa” game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Error as below:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the "Gumbaa" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a SpriteRenderer to the game object "Gumbaa". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. UnityEngine.Renderer.get_bounds () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/GraphicsBindings.gen.cs:1007) EnemyMovement.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/EnemyMovement.cs:21)

And my game also got automatically pause whenever I clicked play button.

When I tried to Add Component 'SpriteRenderer' to Gumbaa, I then received another error message as below: Can't add component 'SpriteRenderer' to Koopa Troopa because it conflicts with the existing 'MeshFilter' derived component!

[Screenshot of inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQTOc.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float speed = 2.7f;
public LayerMask EnemyMask;

Transform myTrans;
float myWidth, myHeight;
Rigidbody2D rb;
SpriteRenderer mySprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    myTrans = this.transform;
    rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

    mySprite = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
    myWidth = mySprite.bounds.extents.x;
    myHeight = mySprite.bounds.extents.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () 
{
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision (8, 9);
    Vector2 LineCastPos = (myTrans.position.toVector2() +         myTrans.right.toVector2() * myWidth + Vector2.up * myHeight * 1.2f);

    Debug.DrawLine (LineCastPos, LineCastPos +          myTrans.right.toVector2 () * 1.2f);

    bool isBlocked = Physics2D.Linecast (LineCastPos, LineCastPos +     myTrans.right.toVector2 () * 1.2f, EnemyMask);


    if (isBlocked) 
    {
        Vector2 currRot = myTrans.eulerAngles;
        currRot.y += 180;
        myTrans.eulerAngles = currRot;
    }

    Vector2 myVel = rb.velocity;
    myVel.x = myTrans.right.x * speed ;
    rb.velocity = myVel;
}
}
```

Comment: The error says it all. You don't have `SpriteRenderer` attached to the-same GameObject `EnemyMovement` script is attached to. Check your scene

Comment: GameObject is Gumbaa. And I tried to add component 'SpriteRenderer' to its inspector, but received this error message: Can't add component 'SpriteRenderer' to Koopa Troopa because it conflicts with the existing 'MeshFilter' derived component. Can check my screenshot of the inspector

Comment: Is this a 3D(model) object? If so then add MeshRenderer to it instead of SpriteRenderer which is for 2D. If it is a 2D object then remove the MeshFilter that is attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

On your Gumba object, you added the script `EnemyMovement`

In the script, you do

```
mySprite = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
```

This means that the GameObject that has `EnemyMovement` must also have `SpriteRenderer`

In the UnityInspector, do AddComponent and choose `SpriteRenderer`

Knowing if you really need to use a sprite renderer here is up to you